# How long do chilli seeds need to be at 25°C to germinate?

Tags: chili, greenhouse, temperature

I’m able to economically maintain my greenhouse at 25°C for about 4 hours during the day. Generally speaking, is this enough for optimal germination of chilli seeds? Or, do you need to have prolonged periods of keeping the greenhouse at such a temperature?

Also, besides keeping the greenhouse above freezing at night, is there any point heating the greenhouse at night? Does heating the greenhouse at night improve germination, or is it a waste of energy?

Comment: You don't need to heat the whole greenhouse to get a seed to germinate. You only need to heat the compost in the plant pot, e.g. by putting the pot on a heat mat.

Comment: Heat mat is a great tip! Once germinated, do you need to maintain 25°?

Comment: And, should you continue to use the heat mat for the lifetime of the plant?

Comment: Keep in mind that it can sometimes frost on the ground when the forecast says it's as high as 41 degrees F. (So, I wouldn't let it get below 42, if you don't want to risk frost.)

Answer (score 1):

Germination rates for chilis vary. In general, sweet peppers germinate faster than hot and hot peppers germinate faster than the ultra hots, but this is just a rule of thumb.

Chilis come from warm climates and so germination is going to improve with warmth. Indeed, consistent warmth is important to push along germination. I would recommend at least 12 hours at 25-27C. With this, you should see plenty of germination in two weeks. Afterwards, a day/night warm/cool cycle will be sufficient for growth.

However, chilis do not appreciate temperatures below 10C, so if your greenhouse can hold above this temp without assistance then you should be fine.

Comment: Great answer. Once germinated, do you need to maintain 25° for 12 hours?